# Sites to practice programming questions

Tags: c++

I am a beginner programmer and I code in java and c++. I am planning to take part in my college's tech fest where they ask programming questions of different difficulty levels.
I would like to know the name of some sites where I can practice programming questions, starting from easy level and advancing to more difficult levels.
Also, is there a specific way according to which I should prepare for the tech fest?

Comment: Because it's your first question on SO, please, don't feel taken aback by the downvotes. In this case they are simply a way of people's expressing disagreement or dislike towards the "tests" you mentioned. Because they are not considered useful, neither is your question. However, more important thing is that questions asking for recommendations are not really welcome here; they tend to produce a lot of noise and little of real facts.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to be more careful next time

Answer (score 4):

[**CPP Quiz**](http://cppquiz.org/) is a rather well-known and well-rated site I know of.

It doesn't have an awful *lot* of questions, but those that are there are nice and require really a lot of thinking and knowledge about the language.

However, CppQuiz is more oriented towards, well, quiz questions. If you want to simply learn the language, trick questions like you mentioned rarely mean much. It's more about knowing your way around the concepts, rather than ability to say "what will that program output" for an arbitrary piece of obfuscated code.

Comment: Thank you for those kind words! :) I am the author of CppQuiz. If anyone would like to help by [creating some questions](http://cppquiz.org/quiz/create), it would be much appreciated! :)